# _flushall() does not work in clearing buffer

Tags: c, buffer

when I am trying to use the _flushall() to clear the buffer, I cannot put the +,-,*,/ sign because it exits, can someone help me?
'

```
printf("Podaj liczbe a:");
_flushall();
scanf_s("%lf", &a);
printf("Podaj dzialanie:");
_flushall();
scanf_s("%c", &dzialanie);
if ((dzialanie != '+') && (dzialanie != '-') && (dzialanie != '*') && (dzialanie != '/'))
{
    printf("Nieprawidlowy symbol dzialania\n");
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}
printf("Podaj liczbe b: ");

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: The call to `scanf_s()` is missing a `size` argument. Please enable compiler warnings. I can't copy the exact line here, because only my eyes can read graphic images of text.

Comment: Please post code and output as text (code blocks). Feel free to add an image as well, but don't use just an image.

Comment: Re "*Please enable compiler warnings*", For example, by passing `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to gcc/clang.

Comment: I have edited the code to the text, can sameone tell me how excatly can I specify the size of the scanf_s?

Comment: Please see the fourth paragraph of the **Remarks** section of the MS [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @PiotrZajkowski, don't use `scanf_s`. Stick to `scanf`. `scanf_s` is a microsoft extension that really don't solve any problem.

Comment: When you use the standard `scanf()` you might want to add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before any `#include` statements. This suppresses the MS nags (one for every usage) and allows you to take notice of more relevant warnings.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I am new to the programming, I have changed the scanf_s to scanf, then I was trying to specify the size of the scanf(), I typed the 1 at the end, but it did not work, finally, when I put the space before the %c it worked.